# How to extract values based on other fields from Json data in R?

Tags: r

From the `json` url mentioned below I want to extract the value of key `"MapName"` : `"..."` based on another Key's value i.e. `"ServerName"` : `"..."`

So far I've used `library(jsonlite)` to extract the json dat into R. I was able to do this in python but not sure how to go about this in R.

```
    library(jsonlite)
    mydata <- fromJSON("https://www.realitymod.com/prspy/json/serverdata.json? 
    1548449002281")
    if(mydata$Data$ServerName == "[PR v1.5.5.2] =HOG= Mixed Maps"){
    print(mydata$Data$MapName)
    }
 Error in if (mydata$Data$ServerName == "[PR v1.5.5.2] =HOG= Mixed Maps") { 
 : argument is of length zero
```

however, I can retrieve values from key by running this:

```
    print(mydata$Data[[1]]$ServerName)
    print(mydata$Data[[1]]$MapName)
```

output:

```
     [1] "[PR v1.5.5.2] =HOG= Mixed Maps"
     [1] "Operation Marlin"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the value of "MapName": "..." corresponding to the attribute of "ServerName": "..." field/key I ask. Something like a for-loop function that takes "ServerName" as an argument and returns corresponding "MapName" after it iterates through all the attributes in mydata$Data[]:

```
    get_map_name <- function(server_name){
      for(i in mydata$Data[[i]]){
        if(mydata$Data[[i]]$ServerName == server_name){
          print(mydata$Data[[i]]$MapName)
        }
      }
    }
```

The above function gives me this error:

```
    get_map_name("[PR v1.5.5.2] =HOG= Mixed Maps")
    Error in mydata$Data[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Here's how I wrote the same function in python. As you can see it returns the "MapName": "value" of the Server I ask:

```
    import json
    import ssl# had to update openSSL from .9 to 1.0
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
    url = 'https://www.realitymod.com/prspy/json/serverdata.json'
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    mydata = json.loads(str(soup))

    def Map_name_of(server_name):
      for i in range(len(mydata['Data'])):
        for k, v in mydata['Data'][i].items():# k and v variables for key & values
          if v == server_name:
            serverNumber = i
      return mydata['Data'][serverNumber]['MapName']
```

I need help in writing a similar function or some other way that extracts the value of key "MapName": "..." corresponding to the attribute of "ServerName": "..." I ask.

Here's [a link](https://www.realitymod.com/prspy/json/serverdata.json?1548449002281) for json-url. This JSON data has 2 primary lists: `Time` & `Data`. Then `Data` list has an array of 44 attributes which each has 50 attributes.  [here's the image of View(mydata) in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg175.png)

Comment: If you try `table(mydata$Data$ServerName)` what happens?

Comment: It returns: table of extent 0 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index that fits the condition with "which":

```
library(jsonlite)
mydata <- fromJSON("https://www.realitymod.com/prspy/json/serverdata.json?1548449002281")

i <- which(mydata$Data$ServerName == "[PR v1.5.5.2] =HOG= Mixed Maps")
print(mydata$Data$MapName[i])
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Didn't know about the which() function. Now I'm going to write this into csv. I might be back here if I run into trouble again for your feedback. Hope you don't mind. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Hi, if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.